# how to execute an interface on SAP EM Data Browser

Tags: sap-erp, sap-basis

I have a SAP EM test case like this:

1. Logon to SAP EM (SAP Event Management)
2. Go to SE16 (Data Browser should be displayed)
3. Check the entry of a table
4. Run an interface on this table

But I cannot find anywhere that I can enter an interface (or script?) to run.

Comment: What is interface in your mind? If it's OOP entity, it cannot be directly executed on smth, as it is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Use Transaction Code SE38 to execute jobs or programs.